# problem to create pattern like minesweeper with C#

Tags: c#, loops, design-patterns, nested

first at all, i'm new at C#, so, I apologize if I ask something somewhat "so newbie". Well, here the thing:

I'm trying to create a pattern, just like the game: **Minesweeper** 'cause i'm making a simple game, a chess game, so my big problem right now is that i can't create the columns efficiently, so, here's my code:

```
class chessGame
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string EX = "X";
        const string OU = "O";
        const int VALUE_X = 8;

        int numRows = 0;
        int numCol = 0;

        while (numRows < VALUE_X)
        {
            for (numCol = 0; numCol < VALUE_X; numCol++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(OU);
            }
            for (numRows = 0; numRows < numCol; numRows++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(EX);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

also, i don't know at all if that's the way create the columns and rows with that *nested loop*, so, if someone can help me with this, or just someone can help me to do it right with my actual code, thank you so much!

and for the record, here's what i see in the console right now:

[image]

beforehand, thank you for your advices to all of you guys!

Comment: It might be easier to track the state of objects on your board in a 2D array. For instance `var grid = new int[8, 8];` And then you can iterate over the contents in nested for loops, one for each row, and an inner loop for each cell in each row: `for (int i=0; i<8; i++) { for (int j=0; j<8; j++) { Console.Write(grid[i, j]); } Console.Write('\n'); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        const string EX = "X";
        const string OU = "O";
        const int VALUE_X = 8;
        bool writeToggle = true;
        int numRows = 0;
        int numCol = 0;

        for (numRows = 0; numRows < VALUE_X; numRows++)
        {
            for (numCol = 0; numCol < VALUE_X; numCol++)
            {
                if (writeToggle)
                {
                    Console.Write(EX);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(OU);
                }
                writeToggle = !writeToggle;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is some code which should generate your pattern. Note the use of `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine` so it does not skip a line everytime a character is printed. Also, the bool `writeToggle` is used to alternate between X and O.

Comment: bro, thank you so much for taking the time to do that, really apreciate it, works perfectly! so, gonna practice more with this, also, that `writeToggle` kinda confused me, but thanks anyway, with time i'll be able to understand this completly!

Answer (score 4):

`WriteLine`, as the name implies, writes an entire line (and puts a newline at the end). Not so great for doing more than one column in your setup!

A typical solution is to just use `Console.Write`, sometimes with [`Console.SetCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition) so you can write individual "cells" at a time.

Another fairly simple approach is to pre-compute each row as a single string, then `WriteLine` that.

Either way, you'll need to rework your loops fairly significantly to get the effect right.

Comment: when you say that is not great to do more than one column, i mean.. i have to do an 8 x 8 pattern, so, it's better the typical solution that you said? , but, i also gonna try to do each row as single string! :)

Comment: @Diego He meant the way you used the `Console.WriteLine()` it is not great for what you are trying to achieve. The way your logic is done could be fix using the solution he gave but if you are willing to change the way your loop works you can manage to use `Console.WriteLine()` properly

Comment: @Franck thanks, now I understand, gonna practice more, thanks for the advice. :)

Answer (score 2):

To get started, you want to change the two inner `WriteLine()` calls to `Write()`.

But really, you want to start thinking in terms of a the whole board, where you have a 2D array to represent the status of the board. Then write a function to output the whole array.